# C# Конверсия индексов Jagged массива содержащего другой Jagged массив. Tilemap

Tags: c#, массивы, разработка-игр, математика, методы

Имеется объект Cell который необходимо достать из массива Maps[][] методом  World.GetCell(uint x, uint y). Maps[][] в свою очередь содержит так же джаггед массивы. То есть метод должен позволять обращать к массиву как к одному целому, а не состоящему из множества.
Боже упаси делать, что то вроде `List<List<>>` и т.д. Вопрос сложный, если что спрашиваете.

Пример как использовать данный метод для нахождения позиции тайла в пикселях:

```
Vector2(World.GetCell(uint x, uint y).X * размерТайла, 
         World.GetCell(uint x, uint y).Y * размерТайла,)
```

Небольшой график, что бы показать что я имею ввиду. Цветные цифры представляют мнимый массив индексы которого нужно получить:

[image: График]

Комментированный код для примера:

```
public static class Config
{
    public static byte MapSize = 64;
    public static ushort WorldSize = 128;
}

public enum CellType : uint
{
    SomeTypeOne,
    SomeTypeTwo
}

public struct Cell
{
    //public uint X; //Легкий вариант с сохраняемыми индексами, но жрет 
    //память ясное дело
    //public uint Y;
    public CellType CellType;

    public Cell(CellType cellType)
    {
        CellType = cellType;
    }
}

public struct Map
{
    public uint Id;
    //public uint X;
    //public uint Y;
    public Cell[][] Cells;

    public Map(uint id)
    {
        Id = id; 
        //Запихиваем прямо в конструкторе
        Cells = new Cell[Config.MapSize][];
        for (var i = 0; i < Config.MapSize; i++)
            Cells[i] = new Cell[Config.MapSize];
    }
}

public class World
{
    public Map[][] Maps = new Map[Config.WorldSize][];
    //public List<Map>; //более приемлемый вариант

    public void GetCell(uint x, uint y) =>
        throw new NotImplementedException(); //Вот сюда засунуть метод

    public World()
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < Config.WorldSize; i++)
            Maps[i] = new Map[Config.WorldSize];
    }
}
```

Думаю можно пробегаться через цикл, но это очень накладно особенно если массивы 64 на 64 и их много. Эпик вариант:

```
for(var i = 0; i < Config.WorldSize; i++)
{
    for (var j = 0; j < Config.WorldSize; j++)
    {
        for (var k = 0; k < Config.MapSize; k++)
        {
            for (var g = 0; g < Config.MapSize; g++)
            {
                var position = new Vector2(k * tileSize + i * tileSize * Config.MapSize,
                    g * tileSize + j * tileSize * Config.MapSize);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

///К вопросу не относиться

Кстати объект World будет весить около 2 гигов в памяти с данным кодом(Хотя со сжатием сохраняется по частям вполне норм через ZeroFormatter). Да, да знаю что грузить это надо динамически, а не все и сразу.

Comment: трижды прочитал, но так и не понял что во что нужно сконвертировать =( Понятно, что вам нужен алгоритм для перехода от одной системы координат к другой, но не понятно из какой в какую вы хотите перейти. Из "мировых" координат к локальным для map или cell, наоборот или еще как-то? Почему использован массив jagged, а не прямоугольный если у вас четкие прямоугольные области? Или это тоже упрощение?

Comment: Не именно координаты, а индексы, То есть когда хочешь взять Cell из массива World.Maps[][] не писать как World.maps[индекс][индекс].map[индекс][индекс], а писать Wolr.GetCell(index, index) в функции как то посчитать эти индексы и вернуть Cell из Maps[][] обращаясь как к одному целому массиву.

Comment: Jagged arrays в c# буквально быстрей работают

Comment: Ок, значит задача все таки перейти от мировых координат к координатам ячейки. Это довольно просто, сейчас опишу на основе ваших структур.

Comment: по поводу быстрей - это смотря для каких целей. Если нужно работать с матрицами или любыми другими строго прямоугольными структурами, то обычные прямоугольные массивы имеют ряд преимуществ, в том числе по скорости доступа к элементам, просто по смещению.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поправьте если не правильно понял вашу идею.

- `Config.WorldSize` - количество элементов `Map` в объекте `World` по вертикали и горизонтали.
- `Config.MapSize` - количество элементов `Cell` в объекте `Map` по вертикали и горизонтали.

Тогда для нам потребуется два перехода: от общемировых координат к координатам `Map` внутри `World` и последующий переход к координатам `Cell` внутри `Map`.

```
public Cell GetCell(uint x, uint y)
{
    //координаты Map внутри World 
    uint xMap = x / Config.MapSize;
    uint yMap = y / Config.MapSize;
    //координаты Cell внутри Map
    uint xCell = x % Config.MapSize;
    uint yCell = y % Config.MapSize;
    //ну и отдаем найденную ячейку
    return Maps[xMap][yMap].Cells[xCell][yCell];
}
```

---

О том, почему это работает:

Рассмотрим следующую картинку

```
|0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8| //сквозная нумерация (мировые координаты)
|--0--|--1--|--2--| //нумерация регионов (Map в вашем случае)
|0|1|2|0|1|2|0|1|2| //нумерация внутри региона
```

Теперь возьмем для примера мировую координату 4 и посмотрим как из нее получить все остальное. Известна длина региона - 3. Следовательно если мы разделим нашу мировую координату на длину региона, то мы получим сколько целых регионов уместится до нашей координаты, а так как нумерация регионов начинается с 0, то полученное число будет номером региона, в который попала данная координата.

```
|0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|
         ^          4 / 3 = 1
|--0--|--1--|--2--|
```

Осталось получить смещение внутри региона. Зная длину региона, мы можем использовать деление с остатком. Остаток всегда меньше делителя, следовательно может принимать любые целые значения от 0 до N-1, где N - длина региона. Как не сложно заметить - эти значения совпадают с номерами ячеек внутри региона.

```
|0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|
         ^          4 % 3 = 1
|0|1|2|0|1|2|0|1|2|
```

---

На всякий случай: все использованные арифметические операции строго целочисленные.

И еще одна оговорка, такое простое решение подходит только для случая строго прямоугольных областей. Если же `Map` будет содержать строки разной длины, а Jagged array это позволяет (для этого он и был задуман), то простым решением уже не обойтись, хотя при таком варианте и мировые координаты использовать не получится.

Comment: Годно работает прямо как задумывалось. Хотя я не понял почему нужно делить координаты. Хотелось бы заполнять массив объектов Cell(x,y) пихая в них глобальные координаты. Сколько пытался сделать такой алгоритм о делении даже не задумывался.

Comment: @TermalAlloy думаю теперь понятнее почему нужно делить

Comment: Спасибо большое разобрался, очень полезный метод получился. *Кстати поправите опечатку на 8 строке в коде uint yCell = !x! % Config.MapSize.

Comment: @TermalAlloy поправил, спасибо